# Complex view using HStack, LazyHStack or Grid?

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I have the following code:

```
struct MapPinSheetMoreInfoView: View {
    let item: Place
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 3) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Location")
                    .font(.caption.weight(.semibold))
                    .lineLimit(1)
                if item.address != "" {
                    Text(item.address)
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    Text(item.city + ", " + item.state)
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                } else {
                    Text("N/A")
                }
            }
            Divider()
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Weather")
                            .font(.caption.weight(.semibold))
                            .lineLimit(1)
                        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline, spacing: 3) {
                            Image(systemName: "waveform")
                                .imageScale(.small)
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                            Text("79%")
                                .font(.caption.weight(.regular))
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        }
                    }
                    Divider()
                    HStack {
                        Text("Hello, World!")
                    }
                }
                Divider()
                HStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Hello, World!")
                    }
                    Divider()
                    HStack {
                        Text("Hello, World!")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces this weird, out of place view:

[image]

As you can see, it all out of place - What type of grid system can I utilize to keep the exact percentage of views on a complex view like this? I want something like this:

[image]

What grid system let's me keep percentages and always have the VStack/HStack be that large?

Comment: Use custom layouts, they have an example of equal width layout https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/composing_custom_layouts_with_swiftui.

Comment: Have you tried something very simple like `.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.5)` and `.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.25)`?

Comment: Trying both methods, thanks guys!

Comment: I managed to make it work using `.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)` on the 2 HStacks inside a VStack = 50% | 50%.